# How do I convert a JPEG file into a black and white (1-bit) monochrome TIFF in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jpeg, tiff, image-conversion

JPEG is a scan of a text document so not much to loose in terms of colour/tones.

`convert foo.jpg -flatten -monochrome bar.tif`

gives

`convert: BitsPerSample 1 not allowed for JPEG. 'JPEGSetupEncode' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/496.`

Ideally I would want to adjust brightness during conversion process.

Comment: Could you provide a sample?

Comment: I am afraid it has personal data on it

Comment: I understand, I wondered if you could scan another document, or did you not make the scan?

Answer (score 2):

TIFF files can hold JPEG data, and ImageMagick is trying to save your image as a monochrome JPEG (inside the TIFF), which is not possible.

Add `+compress` or `-compress lzw` in your command to force other format:

```
convert foo.jpg -flatten -monochrome +compress bar.tif
convert foo.jpg -flatten -monochrome -compress lzw bar.tif
```

Comment: If someone wishes to test this solution, the problem can be reproduced with any image by adding -compress jpeg after -monochrome.